# Javascript input validation without needing a form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, validation, input

I'm making this quick internet app, where a user fills in an input field and then clicks a "Next" button. I read on W3Schools about how to do quick and easy Javascript *form* validation, but I want to know if there's a way to do basically the same thing without a form (i.e. `document.getElementById("myInput").value`; but this is not working). The reason for not wanting a form is because when the "Next" button is clicked it performs a page animation then goes to the next page, and I don't want any form submission delay; (just want an input and a button which clicked calls the animation then sets `window.location`).

The type of validation I am doing is just checking if the field is null or not, so I was wanting to do something like this:

**JavaScript:**

```
function ValidateFields() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  if(x == null || x == '') {
    $(".error-msg").animate({opacity: "1"}, 400);
    return false;
  } else {
    $("body").animate({"margin-left": "-200px", opacity: "1"}, 400);
    setInterval("NextPage()", 800); // double animation time
  }
}
function NextPage() {
  window.location = "next.html?uid=false";
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="" />
<input type="button" value="Next" onclick="return ValidateFields()" />
```

But obviously, it will not work (lack of correspondence and basic structure <sup>(lol)</sup>).

Note: I know Javascript or any client-side validation is not ideal but I have balanced the odds and the consequences and I will also consider backing it with ASP or PHP once I put the page on a server and launch it, *if* I notice some odd burst of internet popularity, which I'm not really expecting.

Comment: `document.getElementById("myInput").value` - this probably doesn't work because your input doesn't have an `id`....

Comment: And by the way, I know the functionality of this whole project will not work without a form (not able to parse pretty much any info), but this is just demo-purposes only.

Comment: Oh, oops, when I typed this into my post I accidently changed `id` to `name`. My mistake, I will edit my question.

Comment: An aside, you should do `setTimeout(NextPage, 800)` instead of what you do have.  1) Interval is for repeated events, Timeout happens only once, 2) String eval on the function is a _bad_ habit to get into, just pass in the function reference (note I have no parens or quotation marks).  Unfortunately, I don't know why this is failing for you - that looks like `x` should be pulled correctly.  Try using `$('#myInput')` instead of `getElementById()` and see what happens?

Comment: +1 Wow, thanks! That works! I'm a slight noob at JavaScript, and that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code seems to work (tested with Chrome):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>This works</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="" />
    <input type="button" value="Next" onclick="return ValidateFields();" />
    <div class="error-msg" style="opacity:0">Some error message</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">        
        function ValidateFields() {
          var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
          if(x == null || x == '') {
            $(".error-msg").animate({opacity: "1"}, 400);
            return false;
          } else {
            $("body").animate({"margin-left": "-200px", opacity: "1"}, 400);
            setTimeout("NextPage()", 800); // double animation time
          }
        }
        function NextPage() {
            window.location = "http://www.yahoo.com"; //just a test
        }
    </script>    
</body>
</html>​
```

Let me know if you need more than this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure doing a `.val()` will work well (cross-browser) without a form.  I would add the `form`, and then on the button `.click` function do it like so...

give an id to the button

```
<input type="button" id="mybutton" value="Next" />
```

and the `.click`...

```
$("#mybutton").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ValidateFields();
}
```

That way clicking on the button won't submit the form

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, you can try reading the input text value as

```
var x = $("#myInput").val();
```

or can check the length as follows

```
if ($("#myInput").length){

}
```

Hope it helps.